# MySQL ERROR 2005 on Vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I am getting the following error when importing a file into MySQL on a Vagrant box

> ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host '-' (0)

I first run to extract the data

```
gunzip < /vagrant/app/data/bkup.sql.gz > /tmp/blu.sql
```

And then run the following to import

```
mysql -u root -proot blu < /tmp/blu.sql
```

This gives me the above errors related to an unknown host. I have now idea why this is occurring because the following works just fine and logs me in

```
mysql -u root -proot blu
```

The data I am importing is from a `mysqldump` so should be clean and not contain any errors.

Why is the host issue occurring and how can I solve it?

Comment: apparently your .sql script is not using `blu`. Edit the first line of the sql script and add `use blu;`, or `create database if not exist blu; use blu`

Comment: I don't think its that. I have created the DB and it exists.

Comment: ok. How about adding `-h vagrant.mysql.ip.address` ?

Comment: Running `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -proot blu < /tmp/blu.sql` results in the same error

Comment: odd.. last thing that comes to mind is: `bind_address:0.0.0.0` in `my.cnf`. Try to set that up. Might help..

Comment: No luck I am afraid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124211/discussion-between-unamata-sanatarai-and-jake-n).